# My sites mobile view design is different when not logged in - how do I ensure it's all the same?

Tags: css, design

I'm having trouble with my mobile responsiveness. The issue arises when a user is not logged in (e.g. hits the homepage for the first time).

The desktop site works as expected, no issues there, but the mobile website pushes some of my elements to the left side of the screen, then when the user logs in these go back to the center of the screen as intended. I have included the screenshots below:

User Logged In: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQSRB.jpg
User Logged Out: https://i.stack.imgur.com/36Oqy.jpg

Does anyone have any idea as to why being logged in to an account would have an effect on the mobile design?

Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: Can you share the URL so that I can check the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried inspecting the html code and css in the browser's dev console? It might be some "hidden" element only available when not loggedn in and that could be interfering. Usually you can see which css or element is causing this type of issues, just navigate through the elements